# Removing plot artifacts (SphericalPlot3D)

Tags: plotting

Using `SphericalPlot3D`, I find I get two types of artifact:

1. A discontinuity in the surface reflectance at $\theta=0,2\pi$
2. Little edges, or perhaps gaps between faces, showing in some regions — this depends very much on the angle that the object is viewed from. If you run the code below, it might not show it without some rotation.

They can both be seen in this

[image: Errors]

How do I get rid of them?

Here's the code to reproduce the problem.

```
GreatCircleDistance[a_, b_] := ArcCos[(a.b)/(Norm[a, 2] Norm[b, 2])]

SphereToCart[{r_, ϕ_, θ_}] = r {Cos[θ] Sin[ϕ], Sin[θ] Sin[ϕ], Cos[ϕ]}

TotalDistance[θ_, ϕ_] := 
  3 + 
    Plus @@ 
      (Exp[-10 GreatCircleDistance[SphereToCart[{1, θ, ϕ}], #]^2] & /@
        (PolyhedronData["Icosahedron", "VertexCoordinates"] // N))

SphericalPlot3D[TotalDistance[θ, ϕ], {θ, 0, π}, {ϕ, 0, 2 π}, 
  PlotStyle -> Directive[Orange, Opacity[1], Specularity[White, 10]], 
  Mesh -> None, 
  PlotPoints -> 30]
```

Comment: What version are you using?

Comment: Looks like a discontinuity in the computed normals. Using `ParametricPlot3D[]` instead works: `With[{icos = N[PolyhedronData["Icosahedron", "VertexCoordinates"]]}, ParametricPlot3D[With[{sph = {Cos[ϕ] Sin[θ], Sin[θ] Sin[ϕ], Cos[θ]}}, (3 + Sum[Exp[-10 VectorAngle[sph, pts]^2], {pts, icos}]) sph], {θ, 0, π}, {ϕ, 0, 2 π}, Mesh -> None, PlotPoints -> 30, PlotStyle -> Directive[Orange, Specularity[1, 10]]]]`.

Comment: @Young Version 10.3

Comment: @J.M. I agree it is a problem with normals, I think it might count as an bone fide bug too (the normal calculation is probably missing a factor of two somewhere).

Answer (score 2):

Compute the normal manually (`SphericalPlot` does it from the polygons:

```
SphericalPlot3D[
 TotalDistance[θ, ϕ] /. Abs[x_]^2 -> x^2, {θ, 
  0, π}, {ϕ, 0, 2 π}, 
 PlotStyle -> Directive[Orange, Opacity[1], Specularity[White, 10]], 
 Mesh -> None, PlotPoints -> 30,
 NormalsFunction -> Function[{x, y, z, θ, ϕ, ρ},
   Evaluate@
    With[{r = 
       TotalDistance[θ, ϕ] /. Abs[a_]^2 :> a^2 // 
        Simplify},
     Cross @@ 
      Transpose@
       D[
        r {Sin[θ] Cos[ϕ], Sin[θ] Sin[ϕ], 
          Cos[θ]}, {{θ, ϕ}}]
     ]
   ]
 ]
```

[image]