# Removing a crease artifact in a surface of revolution SphericalPlot

Tags: plotting, smoothing

Consider the surface

```
r[t_, n_: 2, a_: 1,b_: 1] := ((Abs@Cos[t]/a)^(2/n) + (Abs@Sin[t]/b)^(2/n))^(-n/2)
SphericalPlot3D[r[t, 2], {t, 0,  \[Pi]}, {p, 0, 2 \[Pi]}, PlotRange -> {-1, 1}, AxesLabel -> StringPart["xyz", ;;],  Mesh -> False, MaxRecursion -> 5]
```

[image]
There exists a vertical crease where the $\phi=0$ edge meets $\phi=2\pi$. It doesn't disappear with increased `PlotPoints` or `MaxRecursion`. How to smooth it out?

Comment: Any reason why you don't just use `ParametricPlot3D[]` instead?

Comment: @J.M. its easier to interpret in polar/spherical coordinates..trying parametric now

Comment: [Ah, I knew it was asked before...](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/121345)

Comment: goodness that was ~4yrs ago

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The surface normal at a vertex is computed from the polygons surrounding the vertex.  This leads to a discontinuity in the normal at the boundary of the plot where the surface meets itself.

```
ClearAll[showVertexNormals];
showVertexNormals[g_Graphics3D, scale_ : 1, 
  dir_ : Directive[Thin, Black]] :=
 Show[
  g,
  Cases[g,
   GraphicsComplex[pts_, __, VertexNormals -> vn_, ___] :> 
    Graphics3D[{dir, Line@Transpose@{pts, pts + scale*vn}}],
   Infinity]
  ]

r[t_, n_ : 2, a_ : 1, 
  b_ : 1] := ((Abs@Cos[t]/a)^(2/n) + (Abs@Sin[t]/b)^(2/n))^(-n/2)
plot = SphericalPlot3D[r[t, 2], {t, 0, \[Pi]}, {p, 0, 2 \[Pi]}, 
   PlotRange -> {-1, 1}, AxesLabel -> StringPart["xyz", ;;], 
   Mesh -> False, MaxRecursion -> 5];

Show[showVertexNormals[plot, 0.15], ViewPoint -> {5, 0, 0}]
```

[image]

If you can formulate the correct `NormalsFunction`, you can fix this problem:

```
plot2 = SphericalPlot3D[r[t, 2], {t, 0, \[Pi]}, {p, 0, 2 \[Pi]},
  PlotRange -> {-1, 1}, AxesLabel -> StringPart["xyz", ;;], 
  Mesh -> False, MaxRecursion -> 5, 
  NormalsFunction -> 
   Function[{x, y, z, t, p, r}, {Cos[p], Sin[p], Sign[z]}]
  ]
```

[image]

Comment: thnx for posting.. J.M. had pointed me to your other answer

Comment: @lineage My other answer wasn't there when J.M. pointed out the question.  I discovered the other question after I posted this one.  Then I decided to post roughly the same answer there.  I suppose someone might mark them as duplicates.

Comment: oh I see...that's some convoluted timeline ;)

Answer (score 0):

In light of J.M.'s comment [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/121345/removing-plot-artifacts-sphericalplot3d), using `ParametricPlot3D`instead:

```
r[t_, n_: 2, a_: 1,b_: 1] := ((Abs@Cos[t]/a)^(2/n) + (Abs@Sin[t]/b)^(2/n))^(-n/2)
coords = CoordinateTransform["Spherical" -> "Cartesian", {r, t, p}];
ParametricPlot3D[coords /. r -> r[t, 2], {t, 0, \[Pi]}, {p, 0, 2 \[Pi]}, 
 MaxRecursion -> 5, Mesh -> None, PlotRange -> {-1, 1}]
```